# Cognito admin_set_user_password always raises UserNotFoundException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, devise, amazon-cognito

I try to change the password of a Cognito user from my Rails server application (using the [aws-sdk-ruby gem](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby)). But whenever I call:

```
resp = client.admin_set_user_password({
          user_pool_id: Rails.application.secrets.cognito_user_pool_id,
          username:     current_user.email,
          password:     user_params[:password],
          permanent:    true,
        })
```

I get an `Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Errors::UserNotFoundException`. What is remarkable about this is:

- I can change this user's email address just fine using `admin_update_user_attributes` (including the `email_verified`flag).
- the timestamp for last change of this user in Cognito changes, when I call the set password API.

What am I missing? Why do I always receive a UserNotFoundException despite the using being there?

Comment: If you have set the email as username, when you change this email cognito will disable user and create new user with the new email as username. Go check your user pool in console and see what is happeneing.

Comment: That's a very interesting point @NinadGaikwad! Thanks, I will watch it. However, this should not affect changing ones password, right?

Comment: Changing password is fine. Username is used as a primary key to identify your user, hence the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Is your user name the *email address* or the ID like **73cf6459-xxxx-42e3-ab40-0f93113768fe** under cognito user pool.

Comment: Hm, interesting! Because despite picking "email" as the primary ID, Cognito adds these generated IDs it then uses as primary ID. So will I have to store each users Cognito ID in my backend as well (in addition to the email address)? The strange thing here is: changing the email by referencing the user via email (instead of Cognito ID) seems to work fine.